# Is there a command to toggle the Animation Pane and/or Selection Pane?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, pane

Is there a VBA command that will allow me to toggle panes such as the Animation and Selection?

These panes close themselves when I close the file. I would like to be able to set up my environment the way I like in one click. Bonus points if I can position the pane with x,y coordinates.

The commands that I've seen apply only to Notes, Slide Sorter and Normal views.

Comment: I'm all but certain that what you've found is all there IS to find. I don't think there's any object model access to Selection, Animation, etc. panes. It'd be a useful thing, though; please consider submitting a feature request to https://powerpoint.uservoice.com  The program managers/developers really do watch what's submitted there.